# How to track profile viewers in Rails3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

I'm working on Rails3.2 application. Is there any gem to track profile viewers, means who is seeing our profile.

Thanks

Comment: do you want to track between the app of from external ip too

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to write, do you need gem to do this?
Just add appropriate

```
before_filter :add_visit, only: :show
```

in your UsersController (or how you name it).

Also, [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity) may be useful.